# Getting error while retriving followers using FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, fhs-twitter-engine

I integrated FHSTwitterEngine in my app for retriving followers from Twitter. It is working fine for 5 times after that it will give error like below.

```
Error Domain=Twitter successfully processed the request, but did not return any content Code=204 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Twitter successfully processed the request, but did not return any content error 204.)"
```

I am trying like this

```
NSMutableArray *followersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFollowersForUser:[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername] isID:YES withCursor:@"-1"];
if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
     NSLog(@"Getting error and the error is %@",dict);
}else{
    if ([[dict allKeys]count]>0) {
        [followersArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"users"]];
        for (int m=1; m!=0; ) {
           dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFollowersForUser:[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername] isID:YES withCursor:[dict objectForKey:@"next_cursor_str"]];
           if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
               NSLog(@"Getting error and the error is %@",dict);
               break;
           }else{
               m = [[dict objectForKey:@"next_cursor"] intValue];
               [followersArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"users"]];
           }
        }
        NSLog(@"The followers list is %@",followersArray);
    }
}
```

Please suggest me how can i resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFollowersForUser:[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername] isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];
```